# Как правильно отключить кластеризацию для objectmanager в Yandex Map Api?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, карты, yandex-maps-jsapi, cluster

В проекте выводится некоторое количество точек на карту Yandex, для вывода используются objectManager, так как точек немного (~200), то кластеризатор не нужен. Но при выключении его, точки прекращают выводится в принципе, никаких ошибок нет, просто пустая карта. Этот код

```
objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
    clusterize: true
});
```

работает, точки выводятся, но есть не нужный кластеризатор. А вот этот код не выводит ничего

```
objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
    clusterize: false
});
```

В чем может быть проблема? Пробовал уменьшить количество точек, не помогает

Answer (score 1):

Столкнулся с похожей проблемой.
У меня дело было в том, что у объектов не было свойства:
"type":"Feature"

```js
{
"type":"FeatureCollection",
"features":[{"id":1151,
              "type":"Feature",
              "geometry":{"type":"Point",
                           "coordinates":["56.180858","37.640920"]}
```